# FreeBSD is set to UTF-8, but seems to display in ASCII

Tags: unicode, encoding, utf-8, freebsd

I have FreeBSD 10.3 that boots into console (no x at all), console shell is csh.  I’m trying to get it to use UTF-8. I’ve followed instructions from the handbook, changed my *login.conf* file (and rebuild the database) and shell config files. Now running

```
locale
```

tells me that all is set to UTF-8, but when I try to open a Unicode text file, it appears as if a standard  ASCII codes are used. 
I have another machine running FreeBSD 10.3 (actually, PC-BSD), that has identical set of fonts and runs same shell (in console mode), where everything works fine. I can’t pinpoint any differences in configuration, as far as UTF-8 settings are concern.

Any Idea what I’m missing?

Comment: @TalhaIrfan don't use `inline code` to highlight random terms.

Comment: @CodeCaster Apologies! I have seen inline code being used for tools here as well, so have been unsure there

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Do you have `kern.vty=vt` in `/boot/loader.conf`? [You need to change the console driver from *sc* (default) to *vt* for UTF-8 support in console](https://wiki.freebsd.org/Newcons) (only for FreeBSD >= 9.3 and FreeBSD >= 10.1).

Quick way:

```
echo 'kern.vty=vt' >> /boot/loader.conf
# Default global locale
# For (ba)sh
echo 'export LANG=fr_FR.UTF-8' >> /etc/profile
echo 'export MM_CHARSET=UTF-8' >> /etc/profile
# For (t)csh
echo 'setenv LANG fr_FR.UTF-8' >> /etc/csh.login
echo 'setenv MM_CHARSET UTF-8' >> /etc/csh.login
```

If you boot FreeBSD from grub2, add the line `set kFreeBSD.kern.vty=vt` in the FreeBSD's menuentry to your grub configuration file.

(then restart - change fr_FR to your own locale)

Or rebuild your kernel with:

```
include GENERIC
ident MY_KERNEL_NAME

nodevice sc
device vt
device vt_vga # only for i386/amd64
```